# Why doesn't this work? Is the array not correct?

Tags: powershell

I have a bunch of scripts I sort of 'inherited'. Going through each one and updating as necessary. Have one though that does not work and I do not know if the array is created correctly or not. The end result is nothing returned for the adapter index.

Am I doing this correctly?

```
$netip = (Get-NetIPAddress | ? AddressFamily -eq 'IPv4' | ? IPAddress -ne '127.0.0.1').IPAddress;
$Targetip = @();

ForEach ($ip in $netip) { $Targetip += $ip };

For ($i = 0; $i -lt $Targetip.Length; $i++) 
{
    (Get-NetRoute | ? NextHop -eq $Targetip[$i]).ifIndex
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? If that loop returns anything it basically means that one interface on the machine is acting as a default gateway for another interface on the machine

Comment: That's what i'm trying to determine - which adapter is acting as a default gateway for another adapter on a system. But some things are not known to begin with, and I need to automate this for inclusion in a future project to determine this on systems in the network.